# Finding closed form of the following recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Find the closed form of the following recurrence relation

$$
a_n=a_{n-1}+6a_{n-2}+3^n   
$$

where
$$
a_0=5,a_1=0
$$

So I am comfortable finding closed form of these recurrences when it is only two terms. The $3^n$ is what is confusing me. So my question is that is the characteristic polynomial of this problem

$$
\lambda^2=\lambda+6+9
$$

into

$$
\lambda^2-\lambda-15
$$
or am I not working with $3^n$ correctly? IF this is correct, i know we would move into finding the zeroes and subbing them back into the equation, but I am not sure that this is correct

EDIT: Using the comments, I got that $a_n = 2(3)^n+3(-2)^n+3^n $

I believe this works with $a_3$.

Comment: You should get ${3\over 5}n3^n +\alpha 3^n+\beta (-2)^n.$ The coefficients $\alpha$ and $\beta$ can be determined by the initial conditions $a_0$ and $a_1.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a step-by-step solution which reduces the problem to a linear homogeneous recurrence with constant coefficients, which can be solved with standard techniques.

The exponential term can be "absorbed" into the recurrence by dividing by $\,3^{n-2}\,$ and defining $u_n = \dfrac{a_n}{3^n}\,$:

$$
\begin{align}
a_n=a_{n-1}+6a_{n-2}+3^n \quad&\iff\quad 9 \cdot \frac{a_n}{3^n} = 3 \cdot \frac{a_{n-1}}{3^{n-1}} + 6 \cdot \frac{a_{n-2}}{3^{n-2}} + 9
\\ &\iff\quad 9 u_n = 3u_{n-1}+6u_{n-2}+ 9
\\ &\iff\quad 3 u_n = u_{n-1} + 2u_{n-2} + 3 \tag{1}
\end{align}
$$

The constant term can then be "absorbed" by trying a constant translation $\,u_n = v_n + \lambda\,$ in $(1)\,$:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
3(v_n + \cancel{\lambda}) = (v_{n-1}+\cancel{\lambda}) + 2(v_{n-2}+\cancel{\lambda}) + 3 \quad\iff\quad 3 v_n = v_{n-1} + 2v_{n-2} + 3 \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

The resulting recurrence $(2)$ is identical to $(1)$, so this substitution does not work because the constant term cannot be eliminated this way (which actually happens because the characteristic polynomial has $1$ as a root). Next try in such cases is a linear transformation $u_n = v_n + \lambda n\,$:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
3(v_n+\bcancel{\lambda n}) &= \big(v_{n-1}+ \lambda(\bcancel{n}-1)\big) + 2\big(v_{n-2}+\lambda(\bcancel{n}-2)\big) + 3
\\ \iff\quad\quad\quad\quad 3 v_n &= v_{n-1} + 2 v_{n-2} - 5\lambda + 3 \tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

This one works, by choosing $\lambda = \dfrac{3}{5}$ to cancel the constant term in $(3)$, so $\,u_n=v_n + \dfrac{3}{5}n\,$ satisfies:

$$
3 v_n = v_{n-1} + 2 v_{n-2} \tag{4}
$$

The latter is a linear homogeneous recurrence with constant coefficients. The characteristic polynomial is $3t^2-t-2$ with roots $\big\{1, -\frac{2}{3}\big\}$, so $v_n = c_1 + c_2 \cdot \dfrac{(-1)^n2^n}{3^n}$ for some constants $c_1, c_2$. By reversing the substitutions, it follows that:

$$
a_n = 3^n u_n = 3^n\left(v_n+\frac{3}{5}n\right) = c_1 \cdot 3^n + c_2 \cdot (-1)^n2^n + \frac{1}{5} \cdot n \cdot 3^{n+1} \tag{5}
$$

Finally, the constants $c_1,c_2$ can be determined from the initial conditions by solving the system:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
5 = a_0 &= c_1 + c_2
\\ 0 = a_1 &= 3c_1 - 2c_2 + \frac{9}{5}
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $c_n={3\over 5}n\,3^n.$ Then $$c_n=c_{n-1}+6c_{n-2}+3^n$$ Thus the sequence $b_n=a_n-c_n$ satisfies $$b_n=b_{n-1}+6b_{n-2}$$ Now we may apply  classical methods for homogeneous recurrence relations.

**Remark** A particular solution $c_n$ of nonhomogeneous recurrence relation has been guessed by observing that $1/3$ is a single root of the characteristic equation of the homogeneous recurrence relation. Therefore a natural choice is $c_n=cn3^n.$ Then $c$ can be determined as $3/5.$

Comment: I see. So once I solve the recurrence from here, will this be the solution, or will I need to sub it back into the original in someway, as you will be solving for b_n? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I believe you add 3^n to the solution found for b_n.

Comment: @lex320 Once you determined $b_n$ you just reverse the substitution to get $a_n=b_n+c_n$.

Comment: This would be a better answer if it explained how the particular solution $c_n$ was found.

Comment: Are you familiar with the method of generating functions ? Then I can re-edit the answer and finding a particular solution will not be necessary.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc "*are you familiar with...*" $\;-\;$ Not sure whether this was directed at me. Anyway, I was not suggesting you rewrote the answer. But explaining where that particular $c_n$ came from could help the OP and future readers, since the way it is now looks too much like a magic guess.

Comment: @dxiv I was adressed at the asker. Actually guessing a particular solution is a kind of magic, based on experience. The sequence $3^n$ satisfies the homogeneous equation. So the next choice was $n3^n$ times a constant.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I see. So I found the solution for $b_n$ that I have posted in my original question. Then to solve the original recurrence, $a_n$ we can say $a_n$ = $b_n$+$c_n$ or $a_n = \frac{3}{5}n3^n +2(3)^n+3(-2)^n$

Answer (score 0):

The recurrence

$$
a_n-a_{n-1}-6a_{n-2}=3^n   
$$

is equivalent to

$$
\left(\matrix{a_n^1\\ a_n^2}\right)=\left(\matrix{0&1\\ 6&1}\right)\left(\matrix{a_{n-1}^1\\ a_{n-1}^2}\right)+\left(\matrix{0\\ 3^n}\right)
$$

but

$$
\left(\matrix{0&1\\ 6&1}\right) = T\cdot \Lambda\cdot T^{-1}=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & -1 \\
 3 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 0 \\
 0 & -2 \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & -1 \\
 3 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)^{-1}
$$

then

$$
T^{-1}A_n = \Lambda T^{-1}A_{n-1}+T^{-1}b_n 
$$

now calling $\mathcal{A}_n = T^{-1}A_n$ we have the equivalent sequence

$$
\mathcal{A}_n = \Lambda \mathcal{A}_n+T^{-1}b_n 
$$

so the homogeneous has the solution

$$
\mathcal{A}_n^h = \Lambda^n\cdot c_0 
$$

Making the particular as $\mathcal{A}_n^p = \Lambda^n\cdot c_0(n)$ after substitution we have

$$
\Lambda^n\cdot c_0(n) = \Lambda\cdot\Lambda^{n-1}\cdot c_0(n-1)+T^{-1}b_n 
$$

or

$$
c_0(n) = c_0(n-1) + \Lambda^{-n}\cdot T^{-1}b_n 
$$

and thus

$$
c_0(n) = \sum_{k=0}^n\Lambda^{-k}\cdot T^{-1}b_k 
$$

and finally

$$
\mathcal{A}_n = \mathcal{A}_n^h + \mathcal{A}_n^p = \Lambda^n\cdot c_0 + \Lambda^n\cdot\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\Lambda^{-k}\cdot T^{-1}b_k \right)
$$

hence

$$
A_n = T\cdot \mathcal{A}_n
$$